# How to remove the first top border of the table in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, user-interface

I have created a left side menu. It is a static table view with 6 rows.

As you can see here, there is a first top border - number (1) - of the table view. I try to get rid of that using code below to make the color of that border similar to the background in willDisplayCell but it didn't work:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.layer.borderColor = deSelectedColor.CGColor
    }
```

Any idea to remove that first top border?

Thank you

[image: Current table View]

EDIT:

I have a solution for this but somehow still facing a little bit of problem.

```
var border = CALayer()
border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 99, CGRectGetWidth(cell.frame), 1)
border.backgroundColor = borderColor.CGColor        
cell.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

I turn off the separator from main story board and try to redraw the bottom border for each cell. That worked great but the first cell did not have a bottom line and I could not figure it out...

[image: After deleting separator and redraw]

Comment: You could add a `height = border width` CALayer or UIView to mask the top border

Comment: sorry, I don't understand. Why height = border width? I just need to eliminate the top thin line of the table which is below number (1)

Comment: I had such issue and I found it is not easy to just remove one top border, so I add a view or layer to  mask the border to have same effect

Comment: I got it, you mean another thing that lay on top of the border to hide it?

Comment: yes. but be careful the cell is reused. I also need someone can have a great solution for this

Comment: Please try the solution above and see if you get problem similar to mine or not

Comment: I think cell.layer.borderColor = deSelectedColor.CGColor will remove all border colors, not only top border

Comment: thank you, you saved my day, sometimes so silly and could not see what is going on

Comment: kindly update what you found for a potential answer

Comment: Maybe with using an EdgeInset for the first cell?